# Restricted API Access By only for Android app

Tags: php, android, rest, api

Here is my API call link :

http://192.168.0.107/AYURV/api/V1/user/signup.php

> This link only access by only specific android app how can do that?

Advance Thanks.

Comment: there is no way to 100% prevent others of using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the request sender send a UserAgent and device and app version
This way you can filter incoming requests based on this information on the server side, and reject the ones that don't match.

Comment: Thank you for above information. How to check in server side can you please send me one example.

Comment: i see you are using php, but it should be the same in all languages.
when you receive the request object, it has headers, you check the headers for ```User-Agent```, and any other headers YOU the developer choose to add, you add them during construction of the request